# Passing Strings FROM Windows Form Input Boxes TO Batch File

Tags: vb.net, winforms, batch-file, user-interface

I have a batch file that asks the user for three separate pieces of information. I want to make a GUI out of this for ease-of-use but I'm not sure where to begin. I have a Windows Form with three separate boxes of text and a submit button.

Is this even feasible? I've seen plenty of results for passing batch arguments to VB.Net but none regarding the other way around.

Comment: It's very feasible to create a program in VB that writes out to a file.  Is that what you want?  Can you give some more detail?

Comment: Sure. My batch file prompts the user for three separate pieces of information, one at a time. I actually want to make it so that these pieces of information come from three separate input boxes in a Windows Form and then have that information get passed to the batch file in order for it to actually do it's thing.

The batch file asks the user their name, the department they are shadowing, and their ID number and then places that information into the appropriate folder which is named with the person's ID and the date. I have everything figured out, I just need to iterate it in WIN Forms.

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for this site, as potentially it has many solutions, and you're supposed to have tried to solve it yourself.  However, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you require isn't what I first thought (as per the comments), but it's still possible.  There are a couple of ways that you tackle it:

The first way is to convert the batch file to take the 3 pieces of information as arguments, then when the user hits Submit in your GUI, grab the text box contents, invoke the batch file and pass in the info as the arguments.

The other way is, if the batch file only creates a folder or some other simple stuff like that, think about converting it all into VB, so the application creates the folder too.  This may be easier than figuring out how to run a batch file from VB.

Comment: Converting the batch to take the variables as arguments is exactly what I was shooting for. I'm just not that well versed with batch files so I wasn't sure if something like that would work. Thank you!